# AWS: Using the application load balancer with ECS - Requests not reaching tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, listener, load-balancing, amazon-ecs

When I send requests using the ALB's DNS host, the listener's path, and the web services endpoint path, I don't get a response within the expected timeframe, which I've determined by successfully sending
requests directly to each of the tasks using their public ip addresses, they return successful responses.

For example:

The ALB's DNS entry: http://myapp-alb-11111111.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
The web app, "abc", listens on port 80 for requests on "/api/health".
The web app is using "abc-svc/*" as the path in the listener.
The web app was assigned a public ip address of 10.88.77.66.

Sending a GET request to 'http://10.88.77.66/api/health' is successful.
Sending a GET request to 'http://myapp-alb-11111111.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/abc-svc/api/health' does not return within several minutes, which is not expected behavior.

I've looked through the logs, but cannot find anything that is amiss. I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions...

AWS CONFIGURATION
I have three docker images that are running in ECS. Each image is assigned to a separate service. Each service has a single task. Port 80 is open in the security group from the Internet to the ALB. Port 80 is open from the ALB to each task. The ALB's listener for port 80 is using path-based routing. There is a separate, unique path for each service. Each task contains a docker linux, spring boot 2, web service. Each web service's router has a "/api/health" route that expects a GET request with no parameters and returns a simple string. We are not using HTTP or SSL at this time.

Thank you for your time and interest.

Mike

Comment: When it does return, what does it return? a timeout, an http status code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a different reason for that but some of the common issues that you can debug

- Check health check for each target group under LB target group, if its unhealthy LB will never route the traffic
- Verify the target port is correct
- Verify Target group associated properly with LB and is not showing unused.
- Verify LB security group
- Check the response from LB is it `gateway timeout` or `service unavailbe` if `gateway timeout` its not reachable if `service unavailable` probably restarting
- Services Event logs, check that service is in steady-state or not, if not its mean restarting again and again
- Check deployment logs of service, if you see unhealthy target group message then update the target group health path with status code